# Get onCreateOptionsMenu in cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

i want to build an android app with cordova. In this app we use the (native) actionbar and want to add buttons to it from a cordova plugin. I have got a question about how i can get the onCreateOptionsMenu event inside my plugin. I need it because the plugin receives the data with the active buttons (depends on each view). Is there a way to do that in my plugin?

```
/*
 * Hook in Cordova for menu plugins
 *
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.postMessage("onCreateOptionsMenu", menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I saw that they had something like this in their CordovaActivity.java, but I don't know how I can receive this inside my plugin?

Please help me,

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see `CordovaPlugin.onMessage(String id, Object data)`?

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java#L140

I think you could probably implement this method in a custom plugin and listen for the     `"onCreateOptionsMenu"` message ID and then manipulate the options menu?

I haven't tried anything like this before but I think this might be how it's done.

Comment: Sorry I had not time at work to use this until now. I will tell you in the next few days. So I just do this inside my plugin method and the method that you postet above? What do you mean by listening for the "onCreateOptionsMenu"? Sorry I am very new to Java, we are C#-Developers here :D

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I did get some events (eg. onPageStarted), but not onCreateOptionsMenu.  Maybe it has been removed? (I'm using Cordova 9.0, Android 8.1.0-dev)

Answer (score 1):

I think from my understanding you want to add native functionality to hybrid app right? so, you need to use cordova.exec API for your case.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf

First thing you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.AndroidApacheCordovaPlugin.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Java code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) 
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```